# SQL Select values of a column only if they are associated with all values of another subset, without using multiple queries

Tags: sql

I am sorry if this is a very basic question, but I have not been able to find an answer anywhere :

Let's say I want to get the products that are sold at both stores a and b, with a single table that associates products and stores. In class, we have been taught this kind of solution :

```sql
select product_id
from product
where store = "a"
and product in (
  select product_id
  from product
  where store = "b"
)
```

This however seems very inefficient to me, especially in a case where a very large table would be used. Is there any way to make a single request that satisfies both conditions, without nesting ?

It feels like there has to be, but being very new to sql I actually have no idea, and I have found this type of thing extremely hard to look up. No matter what I search, I find answers to *similar* problems that don't answer my question.

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: sounds like you need to count IDs that have both a and b stores with a distinct count of 2.

Comment: @D-Shih it's *almost* MySQL, we're working on a DBM our teachers made themselves. It supports *most* of MySQL commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by first filtering for the required criteria followed by a corresponding distinct count:

```
select product_id
from product
where store in ('a','b')
group by product_id
having Count(distinct store)=2;
```

Comment: This only works provided there are only two stores, if store c exists and both a and c sell a given product, it will show up in the result.

Comment: @Crysambrosia perhaps you can elaborate and demonstrate in this [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69f1ed2f6936502ef44b9249ea493a46) where stores a, b and c exist

Comment: My mistake, I had overlooked that ```where``` actually removes the rows where the condition is not met. Once my voting timeout is over I will upvote this solution.

Comment: Actually, my vote is locked until the answer is edited. Maybe make a minor edit so I can vote again

Comment: @Crysambrosia ok no problem, have edited.

Comment: @Crysambrosia FYI the other answer by D-Shih also works without error.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly you can try to use condition aggregate function in `HAVING`

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN store = 'a' THEN 1 END) > 0
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN store = 'b' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Well, that didn't work, but I have no idea whether it's actually invalid or just incompatible with our DBM. There was no error message, but nothing showed up either.